# Magnetic Flux of a lone solenoid and coaxial solenoids

Tags: inductance

If you run a current through a solenoid, does it have any magnetic flux on its own of does it need an externally produced magnetic field for there to be any net flux through the solenoid? The physics problem I am doing consists of 2 coaxial solenoids. One is inside of the other. When calculating the flux through the inner solenoid should I only account for the magnetic field produced by the outer solenoid?

Comment: When you run a current through a solenoid, it generates magnetic flux on its own.

Answer (score 0):

So the inner solenoid has no current thru it?
You also need to describe the relative juxtaposition of the two windings.  Does the outer winding completely cover the inner?